# How is inheritance possible with immutability?

Tags: object-oriented-design, inheritance, immutability

The title almost sums it up but let me be example-led and clearer.

Assuming we have a class:

```
class T:
  def goto(self, value):
    print('go')
```

And a second inheriting class:

```
class A(T):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Now, of course, instances of A can call the goto method.

My question is: Does this break immutability? Do we say: A always inherited T, and T always contained the goto method, so it was not mutated. Or do we say: A precedes T and inherits from T. A is therefore mutated to include the goto method and immutability is broken.

Does that make sense? I tend to think the latter because T could change over time. Therefore, A is not "immutable," so to speak, by virtue of having inheritance.

So it leaves me wondering: Is inheritance incompatible with immutability?

Comment: Sure you are not mixing up changes to a class with changes to an object / instance of that class? When we say a class is immutable, we speak about the latter (to be precise: not providing methods which could change the internal state of an *instance* of the class).

Comment: OK that does make sense @DocBrown. I am not mixing those up. I'm genuinely wondering whether an object that depends on another is to be considered immutable when its methods (and what they produce) can change.

Comment: You *are* mixing those up; when we're talking about immutability, we're *not* talking about changes in the class (it's not about changing the *code* over time). That's not what immutability refers to. It's about not being able to change the *values* of a specific instance (object) *at runtime*, in an executing program. E.g, if in a particular run you create an *instance* of a Superhero class with the name "Iron Man", and there is no way to change that to "Tony Stark" (or anything) during that particular run, then the object is immutable (and the class is a "blueprint" for an immutable object).

Comment: The term 'immutable' refers to the state of an object or variable being unable to change at runtime (i.e. it's about what happens in memory when the program runs).     On the other hand, Inheritance describes a relationship between classes (i.e. the structure of a program's source code) and has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the state of objects or variables, so as far as immutability is concerned, inheritance is a totally irrelevant and unconnected concept.

Comment: People may also talk about the likelihood of class implementations changing as a design or architectural concern, but that's not usually the context in which we discuss "immutability" even though it is clearly a type of mutation. You need to clarify exactly what _you_ mean or are referring to when _you_ say "immutable".

Comment: Wait - did you mean that `goto` method should be an example for a **mutating** method? If that's the case, wth don't you make it such an example? Currently it mutates nothing, Voting to close as "unclear", please edit the question and clarify (and try to make more clear where you mean changes to the class or changes to an object / instance of that class).

Answer (score 4):

Whatever you mean with immutability, immutability is not broken here.

You seem to refer to **classes** and consider that class A is modified by inheritance. But this is not what inheritance is about: class
T exists first, and class A is defined as a specialization of T. This means that the class T continues to exist, unchanged, and class A is defined based on T but with specialized featured. So it is not changed at all but is based right from the start on T.

This being said, immutability is not about classes, but about **instances of classes**. If an instance of T can be immutable, then an instance of A can also be immutable since A does not add anything that could mutate the T instance nor the A instance.

Finally, the name of the `goto()` method and its value parameter suggests that it could change the object state by modifying its position. It this is a correct guess, then neither T nor A would be immutable.

Answer (score 2):

It is not breaking immutability.

Because `A` does not change any member field of `T` instance, and method `goto` in `T` does not allow inherited class to change anything of its instance either.

Comment: OK so in those cases it would be breaking immutability?

Comment: @Learning: What cases would you be referring to?

Comment: Though I am not 100% sure, I guess the OP meant that `goto` method to be an example of a mutating method.

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample: Are you asking if it's theoretically possible that an immutable base class gets derived by a class which allows its own properties to be mutated? Because yes, that's possible. A base class cannot force its inheritors to be immutable. Anything the derived class defines, it has the purview to make (im)mutable as it sees fit. But you're using a confused approach to how you talk about both immutability and inheritance that makes it very hard to understand what it is you're trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2):

> A always inherited T, and T always contained the goto method, so it was not mutated.

Mutability refers to class instances. You're talking about class definitions, and therefore mutability is not relevant to discuss here.

*If you are unsure what I mean by class instances as opposed to class definitions (which I suspect you might be, based on your question), **read up on OOP tutorials immediately**. Understanding the distinction between them is the most central tenet of OOP. Without that understanding, it's impossible to give you an answer to the question you're asking. You can't make bread without knowing what flour is; and you can't discuss OOP concepts such as inheritance and immutability without knowing what objects/instances are.*

An immutable object is one that cannot be changed after it has been instantiated. But at no point during your question or example, you've even touched on the instantiation of any object.

> I tend to think the latter because T could change over time.

Classes do not dynamically change within the scope of a given build or runtime. A definition is strictly defined in a given assembly.

Changes made to the source code during a development cycle have nothing to do with the mutability of objects. These are two completely different worlds that have no bearing on each other.

> So it leaves me wondering: Is inheritance incompatible with immutability?

As discussed, the two have no relation in the way you're trying to point out.

However, what *is* correct, is that if a derived class claims immutability, that its claim depends on the immutability of its base class.

Therefore, it is possible for the derived class to suddenly lose its immutability even though the code for the derived class was not changed. This may initially come across as counterintuitive. But a change in the base class which causes the base class to become mutable, inherently also causes all of its derived classes to become mutable (if they weren't already).

What is also correct, is that it's perfectly possible to have an immutable base class and a mutable derived class. For example:

```
public class Base
{
    public string MyImmutableValue { get; }

    public Base(string val)
    {
        this.MyImmutableValue = val;
    }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public string MyMutableValue { get; set; }
}
```

What is **not possible** is to have a mutable base class and an immutable derived class. When a base class is mutable, its derived classes are automatically also mutable.

Comment: we could argue that it is technically possible to make a mutable class immutable when derived by overlading a setter and disallow the modification. Yes this violate some common respected principle, but it's still doable as long modification to the field is encapsulated at least in a setter method. Another way to have that which does not violate the original base class would be to have a overloadable method which return for instance a boolean, when it returns a specific value, it disallows some specific behaviour that change the state, while the rest of the methods does not alter it.

Comment: @Walfrat: It may technically be possible but it's fraught with LSP violations. Code that handles base instances is going to expect the ability to mutate the object, but its derived type is built to block it. This means that it fails, whether silently (ignore) or loudly (exception); neither of which is an acceptable approach.

Comment: thanks. this is helpful. i asked the question because i was confused not because I already knew the answer :) I thought that was why this site exists.